# Linux - Avoid cat: no such file or directory when file does not exist

Tags: linux, bash

I am checking via a bash script whether a process is running based on the PID stored in a file. I get the error shown above when the file does not exist as the command is trying to access the file and check whether the PID is really there, so it's normal, but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Is there such a way?

The command I am using can be found below.

if kill -0 $(cat "$pid_file")

Thank you in advance.

Comment: show the content of the pid_file - i bet you there is a `\n` at the end of that file.

Comment: In semi-human code: *If $PID_file exists* then kill  kill -0 $(cat "$pid_file").  Also see [if -e](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html).

Possible UNTESTED code:
    if [ -e $pid_file ]
     then
           echo "$pid_file found. Sending signal
           kill -0 $(cat "$pid_file")
     else 
         echo "$pid_file does not exist."
    fi
    done

Comment: thanks for replying, the PID file just stores the PID process number of a running application...so when the application is not running and the file is not generated, I would like to test whether the PID exists anyway just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Try with `cat "$pid_file" | head -n 1 | tr -d "\n"`

Comment: Did you try with `pgrep`? check the `-F` switch.

Comment: I have tried with cat "$pid_file" | head -n 1 | tr -d "\n" but the result is the same...cat: /var/run/my_app.pid: No such file or directory

Comment: Hennes, that would work indeed, but I have other if conditions in the same context so I would rather do not complicate things more with nested ifs...thank you though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[[ -f "$pid_file ]] && (cat "$pid_file" | head -n 1 | tr -d "\n")`

This command will return a non-zero status. If you want an "always return zero" (sacrificing legibility):

`[[ ! -f "$pid_file ]] || (cat "$pid_file" | head -n 1 | tr -d "\n")`

Comment: Oh I see, so basically now I am doing the opposite, if the file exists or the PID exists based on the file...I will change it as your suggestion and come back, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need a condition to check whether the file exists, and if you don't want to see any errors when you attempt to `kill` a PID that no longer exists, redirect its `stderr` to `/dev/null`. You'll end up with something like:

```
PID_EXISTS=$([[ -f "$pid_file" ]] && kill -0 $(<"$pid_file") 2> /dev/null && echo 1 || echo 0)
```

This will store `1` for an existing pid, and `0` for a non-existing one. You may use the variable in a comparison, such as:

```
if [[ $PID_EXISTS -eq 1 ]]; then echo FOUND; else echo NOTFOUND; fi
```

Or just print its result:

```
echo $PID_EXISTS
```

No `cat`. Meow!

Comment: In this case I suggest to purge the not anymore existing PID from the list with a `sed`... Even if low there is a probability that this PID before or after will be used again...

Answer (score 1):

Or, you can just use `pgrep` instead:

```
if pgrep -F "$pid_file" &>/dev/null; then
    echo yep
else
    echo nope
fi
```